# MySQL Workbench [BUG]

Tags: mysql-workbench

so I have a problem where I can't make new table through MySQL Workbench, the name field is just not showing to me nor "Apply" button which should be in the bottom.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Screenshot from MYSQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxz6c.png)

I don't know what should I do right now

Best regards